# facebook graph API: not able to get a list of user's friends

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have created registered an app on developers.facebook.com.

My app runs on the browser, it is a website.

I have created my login button, and facebook users are able to log in succesfully.

However, I'm not being able to consistently retrieve a list of all of the user's friends.

**9 out of 10 times the API will return the friends of the user who also use my app.
1 out of 10 times the API will return the full list of friends.**

This is how I am having the users log into facebook:

```
function loginToFacebook(){ 
    FB.login(function(response){
            FB.api('/me', function(response){
                console.log (response);
                console.log('good to see you, ' +response.name);
            });
    },
    {scope:'email, read_friendlists, user_likes, user_friends, publish_actions, read_mailbox, read_requests'});
}
```

And this is how I am attempting to retrieve a list of ALL of the user's friends:

```
function friendList(){
     FB.api('/me/friends', function(response){
         console.log (response);
     });
}
```

Any suggestions or gotchas I should be looking out for?

Thanks!

Comment: The code is fine.. There may be some privacy setting set by the user that doesnt allow anyone to see his friends...

Comment: But 9 out of 10 seems unusual..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to working now.

I think it was erring because I had JUST registered the app on developers.facebook.com.

Maybe Facebook doesn't give an app full permissions until it has been in existence for a while....